# History of using negative ERRNO values in GNU

Tags: c, linux, history

Is there a [history behind the "negative error" approach](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/errno.html)? That is, in a lot of kernel code and in various Linux-related projects, one does not set the `errno`, but uses [`<errno.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), and return codes are of the format:

---

```
int iErr;
if ( function_successful ) {
    iErr = 0;
} else if ( function_successful && num_bytes_handled > 0 ) {
    iErr = num_bytes_handled;
} else {
    // Error
    iErr = (-EINVAL);
}
return iErr;
```

---

I've grown to use this approach myself when writing drivers, resource managers, libraries, etc, but I've always wondered where the practice originated. I personally find it a clever way to work with error numbers with functions returning `int`, and want to know more about how and where it started.

Thank you.

Comment: Waiting to see the answers. but you usually say "mayday!" or "negative" when things go wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the technique of returning a negative number, and then having the user/system call interface glue stuff the positive version of into `errno` before returning -1, was used in Thompson and Ritchie's original Unix code.

Comment: No, that technique was not used in the original Unix code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, system calls returned either a positive value (in case of success) or a negative value indicating an error code. This has been the case from the very beginning of UNIX as far as I'm concerned. The libc converts the error return to an assignment to `errno` and a return value of `-1` in case of error, or the original return value in case of success.

This approach is needed because the kernel can't set `errno` as it doesn't know where `errno` is. It might be possible to design a system in which the kernel is told where `errno` is, but that's much more complicated than just letting `errno` be assigned by the libc.

Comment: PDP-11 Unix V1 does not do this.  When there's an error, the system call sets the carry flag in the status register, and returns the error code in register `R0`.  On success, the carry flag is cleared, and `R0` holds a return value.  Unix V7 does the same.

Answer (score 1):

At http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/errno.html, Linus Torvalds elaborates on why the errno-variable approach is flawed .

On modern multithreaded POSIX implementations, errno is defined as a macro to work around the multithreading problems that a traditional `extern int errno` variable would have.

As he puts it:

> Too bad that user space has to fix up the *correct* error code
>   returning that the kernel does, and turn it into the "errno" stupidity
>   for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Actually, the glibc does it backwards. We have thread-local storage for years now. The system could just to `_Thread_local int errno` and everything would work fine.